# Work done by the force F - Vector calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

I am having some difficulties doing some line integrals exercises, could someone please check my working and solution?
The question is as follows :

> A particle moves from point $A = (0,0,0)$ to point $B=(2\pi,0,2\pi)$, under the action of the force $\mathbf F=x\ \mathbf i + y\ \mathbf j -z\ \mathbf k$ where $\mathbf i,\mathbf j,\mathbf k$ are the direction vectors.

1. Calculate the work done by the force $\mathbf F$ on the particle if it moves along the conic-helical curve :$\mathbf r(t)= (t\cos t)\ \mathbf i +(t \sin t)\ \mathbf j+t\ \mathbf k$ with $t$ between $0$ and $2\pi$.

My approach was as follows :

Find the integral $$\int_C\mathbf F(x(t),y(t),z(t))\cdot\mathbf r'(t)\mathrm dt$$

I calculate $\mathbf r'(t)$ to be $(\cos t-\sin t)\ \mathbf i+(t\cos t+\sin t)\ \mathbf j +\mathbf k$

$$\int_0 ^{2\pi}(t\cos t\ \mathbf i + t\sin t\ \mathbf j-\mathbf k)\cdot\mathbf r'(t)\mathrm dt$$
this reduced to $$[t^3 + t]_0^{2\pi} = 2\pi(4\pi^2 +1)$$

2. Find the parametric vector equation for the straight line connecting $A$ to $B$, and calculate the work done by the force $\mathbf F$ on the particle as it moves along the straight line.

I think in this question my methods is not correct, but it was as follows :

$$x=t,y=t,z=t\implies\mathbf r(t)= t\ \mathbf i+t\ \mathbf j+t\ \mathbf k$$

I determined the tangent vector to be $\frac{d\mathbf r}{dt}=\mathbf i +\mathbf j -\mathbf k$
then determined the force field of the tracjectory:
$$\int_0 ^{2\pi}(t\ \mathbf i+t\ \mathbf j-t\mathbf k)(\mathbf i+\mathbf j-\mathbf k)\mathrm dt = 2\pi^2$$

3. Determine whether it is conservative, which I don't think I will have a problem with once these are checked.

Comment: In the second part, the particle ends up at a point with zero y coordinate. So you can just set y to be identically zero

Comment: I am not quite understanding how to do part ii, could you give me some hints? Also is part i right ? Many thanks

Comment: Part I is also not correct, unfortunately I am not near a computer so I can't type it efficiently, if no one answers by the time I get home I'll give an answer to your question

Comment: Many thanks Dan !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Lets start with part 1:

We want to calculate the work done by a force field on the particle along a path 
$$ \int \vec{F}(\vec{r}) \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{r} = \int \vec{F}(\vec{r}(t))\cdot \vec{r}'(t) \mathrm{d}t $$
We are given that the path is a conical helix given by
$$\vec{r}(t) = t \cos{t} \;\hat{i} + t \sin{t} \;\hat{j} + t \hat{k} \quad t \in(0,2 \pi)$$
And
$$\vec{F}(\vec{r}) = x \; \hat{i} + y\;\hat{j} + z\;\hat{k}$$
Using the product rule we obtain for $\vec{r}'$:
$$\vec{r}'(t) = (\cos{t} - t\sin{t})\; \hat{i} + (\sin{t} + t\cos{t})\; \hat{j} + \hat{k}$$
And 
$$\vec{F}(\vec{r}(t)) = t\cos{t}\;\hat{i} + t\sin{t}\;\hat{j} + t\;\hat{k}$$
We take the dot product:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\vec{F}(\vec{r}(t)) \cdot\vec{r}'(t) &=&  (\cos{t} - t\sin{t})t\cos{t} + (\sin{t} + t\cos{t}) t\sin{t} + t \\
&=& t\cos^2{t} - t^2 \sin{t}\cos{t} + t\sin^2{t} + t^2\cos{t}\sin{t} + t \\
&=& 2t
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus the resulting integral is:
$$\int_0^{2 \pi} 2t \mathrm{d}t = \left. t^2 \right|_0^{2\pi} = 4 \pi^2$$

For part 2:
We want to parameterize the straight line from $(0,0,0)$ to $(2\pi,0,2\pi)$ in the variable t, you were close with your parameterization however you didn't need y so the correct line is:
$$\vec{r}(t)= t \;\hat{i}+ t\;\hat{k} \quad t\in(0,2\pi)$$
You can likely carry on from there. But if you need more I can continue on

Comment: Many thanks Dan. I will try to finish it when arrive home ,cheers

Comment: No problem it should be clear from then

Answer (score 0):

i'm also struggling with a question like this, the question actually says that F=xi+yj-zk, your answer has taken F to be equal to xi+yj+zk, I worked out part 1 to overall equal 0?
Edit: My rep couldnt comment on the above answer, please make sure he finds this!

Comment: This is comment or follow-up for your own question. Please do not post it as an ANSWER. I suggest you have an EDIT portion in your Question section, and put this question below as a follow-up.

Comment: Wasnt my question

Comment: Ah, right, sorry. Then I recommend you to delete this answer, and ask a new question, referring to this one. So the way this site works is that it is not like a continuum discussion of posts, but one thread is one questions + several answers. We vote to make good answer standout. In such way, in one thread, people see one Question + a few good Answers, in stead of long discussions in time order.